# Playing audio in javascript keeps breaking

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm trying to play audio in javascript and this is what I did (as per another question I saw) :

```
var audio = new Audio('music.mp3');
audio.play();
```

Now the issue I'm getting is that the `mp3` file plays but its broken and it feel as if I'm pausing/playing a DVD really fast. I tried it on different browsers as well (mozilla, firefox, and safari) but still the same. Anyone have any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Try to use the html5 [`audio`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) tag.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is a little strange, but if you check the [**HTMLAudioElement** MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) you will see that:

> An Audio element constructed with `new Audio()` won't be garbage collected so long as playback is in progress. It will continue playing and be audible until `stop()` is called or playback finishes.

**Solution:**

You can create a [HTML5 `<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) element dynamically, and profit from its wide range of controls: `play()`, `autoplay`,`muted`, `volume`, `pause()` and it's [**supported in almost all browsers**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#Browser_compatibility)

**Demo:**

This is a sample demo that creates an `audio` element dynamically and controls it with JavaScript:

```js
var aud = document.createElement("audio");
var source = document.createElement("source");
source.src = "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-13.mp3";
source.type = "audio/mpeg";

aud.appendChild(source);

//Play the Audio file
aud.play();

//Stop it after 5 seconds
setTimeout(function() {
  aud.pause();
  console.log("stopped");
}, 5000);
```

Comment: What's the difference between the audio object and the audio element (when it's not inserted into the DOM)?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It's almost the same thing, but with better browser support and better controls.

Comment: Wow really? Good to know, but that makes no sense.

Comment: Instead of just fooling people, you can provide an alternative and show us your point in action.